# Is there always a pure Nash equilibrium in a resource selection game?

Tags: game-theory, computation, nash-equilibrium, congestion-games

Denote $[r]\triangleq\{1,2,\ldots,r\}$.

Consider a game with $n$ players, $[n]$, each has $m$ strategies, $[m]$.

Each player $i$ has an associated payoff function, which considers only his selected strategy, and the number of players selected the same strategy:
$$U_i:[m]\times[n]\to[0,1]$$

Furthermore, the utility function is monotonically decreasing in the number of players which picked the same strategy, i.e.
$$\forall i\in[n],j\in[m],k\in[n-1]:U_i(j,k)\geq U_i(j,k+1)$$

> **Does this game always have a pure Nash equilibrium?**
>
> **Can we (computationally) find it efficiently?**

---

Notice that the **special case**, where all players are symmetric ($\forall i,j\in[n]: U_i\equiv U_j\equiv U$), the game reduces to an exact potential game and therefore is guaranteed to have a pure Nash equilibrium.

The potential function for the symmetric case would be, given a strategy profile $s$:
$$\phi(s) = \sum_{j\in[m]}\sum_{k=1}^{\#_j(s)} U(j,k)$$

Where $\#_j(s)$ is the number of players in $s$ playing strategy $j$.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, there is always a pure Nash equilibrium. See:

I Milchtaich (1996). Congestion games with player-specific payoff functions. 
*Games and economic behavior* 13 (1), 111-124.

You are interested in the special case of **singleton** congestion games with player-specific payoff functions.

And yes, they can be computed in polynomial time. See Corollary 7 in:

Heiner Ackermann, Heiko Röglin, Berthold Vöcking (2009). Pure Nash equilibria in player-specific and weighted congestion games. *Theoretical Computer Science* 410 (17), 1552-1563.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Rahul. In not convinced, however, by the hardness, as this is a special case of congestion game and not general game.

Comment: Sorry, I misread your definition - you are interested in **singleton** congestion games with player-specific payoffs, my answer would apply to say asymmetric network congestion games. I have edited it.

Comment: Thanks Rahul ! If you are interested, I have a related question posted on [mathoverflow](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/196083/when-does-a-stable-assignment-of-buyers-into-goods-exist), where the payoff to the player is dependent on the number of players picking the same strategy, but might drop to 0 if some players pick the same singleton. Thanks again.